# Split a row into multiple rows (to another dataframe) by date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, row

I have a dataset in pandas that contains date range info:

| Project Name | Project Lead | Start Date | End Date | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Me | Jan 1, 2022 | Jan 5, 2022 | 10 |
| Project 2 | Myself | Mar 1, 2022 | Mar 5, 2022 | 20 |
| Project 3 | I | Jun 1, 2022 | Jun 5, 2022 | 30 |

The end goal is to break each line into a daily entry, counting only workdays, and divide hours by the number of days. Something like this:

| Project Name | Project Lead | Start Date | End Date | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Me | Jan 1, 2022 | Jan 1, 2022 | 2 |
| Project 1 | Me | Jan 2, 2022 | Jan 2, 2022 | 2 |
| Project 1 | Me | Jan 3, 2022 | Jan 3, 2022 | 2 |
| Project 1 | Me | Jan 4, 2022 | Jan 4, 2022 | 2 |
| Project 1 | Me | Jan 5, 2022 | Jan 5, 2022 | 2 |
| Project 2 | Myself | Mar 1, 2022 | Mar 1, 2022 | 4 |
| Project 2 | Myself | Mar 2, 2022 | Mar 2, 2022 | 4 |
| Project 2 | Myself | Mar 3, 2022 | Mar 3, 2022 | 4 |
| Project 2 | Myself | Mar 4, 2022 | Mar 4, 2022 | 4 |
| Project 2 | Myself | Mar 5, 2022 | Mar 5, 2022 | 4 |

I'm still new to Python but this is my attempt:

1. create a function

```
def split_days(row) :
    v_Temp_Start_Date = row["Start Date"]
    v_Temp_End_Date   = row["End Date"]
    v_Workday_Count   = pandas.bdate_range(row["Start Date"], row["End Date"])
    v_Avg_Hours       = round((row["Hours"] / v_Workday_Count), 2)
    
    while v_Temp_Start_Date <= v_Temp_End_Date:
        if v_Temp_Start_Date.weekday() <= 4 :
            T_Temp1 = pandas.DataFrame(row["ProjectName"], row["Project Lead"], v_Temp_Start_Date, \
            v_Temp_Start_Date, v_Avg_Hours)
            T_output = T_output.append(T_Temp1)
        v_Temp_Start_Date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

```
T_Final = pandas.concat(T_Source_Data.apply(lambda row: split_days(row), axis = 1))
```

Completely not working of course but I don't even know where to start to find out what the problem is.

I tried to run it before I post here to get more detail error but my application is behaving and cannot load...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert your dates to datetime objects, you can use date_range to generate row-wise dates which can be exploded.  The rest is calculating the Hours and casting the dates back to the desired string format.

If you are using a linux system, the strftime format will use `%-d` instead of `%#d`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Project Name': ['Project 1', 'Project 2', 'Project 3'],
 'Project Lead': ['Me', 'Myself', 'I'],
 'Start Date': ['Jan 1, 2022', 'Mar 1, 2022', 'Jun 1, 2022'],
 'End Date': ['Jan 5, 2022', 'Mar 5, 2022', 'Jun 5, 2022'],
 'Hours': [10, 20, 30]})

df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

df['Start Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start Date'], x['End Date'], freq='D'), axis=1)

df = df.explode('Start Date')

df['Hours'] = df.groupby('Project Name')['Hours'].transform(lambda x: x/ len(x)).astype(int)

df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%b %#d, %Y')
df['End Date'] = df['Start Date']

print(df)
```

Output

```
  Project Name Project Lead   Start Date     End Date  Hours
0    Project 1           Me  Jan 1, 2022  Jan 1, 2022      2
0    Project 1           Me  Jan 2, 2022  Jan 2, 2022      2
0    Project 1           Me  Jan 3, 2022  Jan 3, 2022      2
0    Project 1           Me  Jan 4, 2022  Jan 4, 2022      2
0    Project 1           Me  Jan 5, 2022  Jan 5, 2022      2
1    Project 2       Myself  Mar 1, 2022  Mar 1, 2022      4
1    Project 2       Myself  Mar 2, 2022  Mar 2, 2022      4
1    Project 2       Myself  Mar 3, 2022  Mar 3, 2022      4
1    Project 2       Myself  Mar 4, 2022  Mar 4, 2022      4
1    Project 2       Myself  Mar 5, 2022  Mar 5, 2022      4
2    Project 3            I  Jun 1, 2022  Jun 1, 2022      6
2    Project 3            I  Jun 2, 2022  Jun 2, 2022      6
2    Project 3            I  Jun 3, 2022  Jun 3, 2022      6
2    Project 3            I  Jun 4, 2022  Jun 4, 2022      6
2    Project 3            I  Jun 5, 2022  Jun 5, 2022      6
```

Comment: great thanks I'll give that a try and mark as answer later once it is fixed. By the way, I can use bdate_range instead to only work on workdays right?