# Split a row in a DataFrame into multiple rows by date range (when and only when date range is across 2 months)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, split

I have a DataFrame where each row identifies a guest with its booking id, name, arrival date, departure date and number of nights.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Booking_ID': ['34532', '43242', '43242', '32414'],
 'Name': ['Me', 'Myself', 'You', 'I'],
 'Start_Date': ['Jan 1, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Jun 1, 2022'],
 'End_Date': ['Jan 5, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Jun 5, 2022'],
 'Nights': [4, 3, 3, 4]})
```

Some clients were guests across two months. For statistical reasons, I need to divide these rows into two different rows: one for nights in the first month and the other for nights in the second month.

What I want to obtain is:

| Booking_ID | Name | Start_Date | End_Date | Nights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34532 | Me | Jan 1, 2022 | Jan 5, 2022 | 4 |
| 43242 | Myself | Mar 31, 2022 | Apr 1, 2022 | 1 |
| 43242 | Myself | Apr 1, 20222 | Apr 3, 2022 | 2 |
| 43242 | You | Mar 31, 2022 | Apr 1, 2022 | 1 |
| 43242 | You | Apr 1, 20222 | Apr 3, 2022 | 2 |
| 32414 | I | Jun 1, 2022 | Jun 5, 2022 | 4 |

I came across this other question: [Split a row into multiple rows (to another dataframe) by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73665310/split-a-row-into-multiple-rows-to-another-dataframe-by-date-range) which is similar and useful, but I'm still unable to obtain what I want.

I modified the code from the previous link:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Booking_ID': ['34532', '43242', '43242', '3241413'],
 'Name': ['Me', 'Myself', 'You', 'I'],
 'Start_Date': ['Jan 1, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Jun 1, 2022'],
 'End_Date': ['Jan 5, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Jun 5, 2022'],
 'Nights': [4, 3, 3, 4]}) 

df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']] = df.apply(lambda x: (pd.date_range(x['Start_Date'], x['End_Date'] - dt.timedelta(days=1), freq='D'), pd.date_range(x['Start_Date'] + dt.timedelta(days=1), x['End_Date'], freq='D')) if x['Start_Date'].month != x['End_Date'].month else (pd.date_range(x['Start_Date'], x['Start_Date'], freq='D'), pd.date_range(x['End_Date'], x['End_Date'], freq='D')), axis=1, result_type='expand')

df = df.explode(['Start_Date', 'End_Date']).reset_index(drop=True)

df['Nights'] = df.groupby(['Booking_ID', 'Name', df.Start_Date.dt.month], as_index=False)['Nights'].transform(lambda x: x/len(x)).astype(int)
```

What I've got is this:

```
     Booking_ID      Name Start_Date   End_Date  Nights

0         34532        Me 2022-01-01 2022-01-05       4
1         43242    Myself 2022-03-31 2022-04-01       3
2         43242    Myself 2022-04-01 2022-04-02       1
3         43242    Myself 2022-04-02 2022-04-03       1
4         43242       You 2022-03-31 2022-04-01       3
5         43242       You 2022-04-01 2022-04-02       1
6         43242       You 2022-04-02 2022-04-03       1
7         32414         I 2022-06-01 2022-06-05       4
```

This is partially what I want.

I don't really care about the date format as that can be easily changed with

```py
df['Start_Date'] = df['Start_Date'].dt.strftime('%b %#d, %Y')
df['End_Date'] = df['End_Date'].dt.strftime('%b %#d, %Y')
```

But I really need:

1. to aggregate all the rows that have the same booking ID, name and month of the Start_Date into 1 row with the column Nights. This results in the nights sum of the aggregated rows, and the Start_Date/End_Date couple resulting in the first Start_Date and the last End_Date of the aggregated rows.
2. If there is a row originated from the previous row split by date range that has a 1 day distance between Start_Date and End_Date but the original number of nights, the Nights value must be changed to 1

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def split_across_months(row):
    start = row['Start_Date']
    end = row['End_Date']
    booking_id = row['Booking_ID']
    name = row['Name']
    
    dates = [start]
    
    while start.month != end.month:
        start = start.replace(day=1) + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
        dates.append(start)
    
    dates.append(end)
    
    rows = []
    
    for i in range(len(dates) - 1):
        nights = (dates[i + 1] - dates[i]).days
        rows.append({'Booking_ID': booking_id, 'Name': name, 'Start_Date': dates[i], 'End_Date': dates[i+1], 'Nights': nights})
    
    return pd.DataFrame(rows)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Booking_ID': ['34532', '43242', '43242', '3241413'],
 'Name': ['Me', 'Myself', 'You', 'I'],
 'Start_Date': ['Jan 1, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Jun 1, 2022'],
 'End_Date': ['Jan 5, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Jun 5, 2022'],
 'Nights': [4, 3, 3, 4]})

df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

result_df = pd.concat(df.apply(split_across_months, axis=1).tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)

print(result_df)
```

It's kind of brute force, but basically if the start and end months are different, you iterate over each month and create a new row. Since, I suspect, there isn't a lot of reservations with thousands of months, this should work ok.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your help. Your solution works fine and I'll use it, but I'm still open to other more pandas-onic ways.

Comment: Bruno, I modified your code in order to manage a row with more that those labels, so his part:
'rows.append({'Booking_ID': booking_id, 'Name': name, 'Start_Date': dates[i], 'End_Date': dates[i+1], 'Nights': nights})'
became 
'new_row = {label: dates[i] if label == 'Start_Date' else dates[i+1] if label == 'End_Date' else nights if label == 'Nights' else value for label, value in row.to_dict().items()}

        rows.append(new_row)'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reindex` + `.repeat` to add rows. You want 1 row per month:

```
num_months = 1 + (df['End_Date'].dt.month - df['Start_Date'].dt.month)
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(num_months)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

> ```
>   Booking_ID    Name Start_Date   End_Date  Nights
> 0      34532      Me 2022-01-01 2022-01-05       4
> 1      43242  Myself 2022-03-31 2022-04-03       3
> 2      43242  Myself 2022-03-31 2022-04-03       3
> 3      43242     You 2022-03-31 2022-04-03       3
> 4      43242     You 2022-03-31 2022-04-03       3
> 5      32414       I 2022-06-01 2022-06-05       4
> ```

---

You can then `.groupby` to generate each month number, and the total number of rows per "group".

```
groups = df.groupby(df.columns.to_list())
month  = groups.cumcount() + 1
rows   = groups.transform('size')
```

> ```
> >>> groups.cumcount() + 1
> 0    1
> 1    1
> 2    2
> 3    1
> 4    2
> 5    1
> dtype: int64
> >>> groups.transform('size')
> 0    1
> 1    2
> 2    2
> 3    2
> 4    2
> 5    1
> dtype: int64
> ```

---

You add the month to get the new end date. You shift the end date to become the next row's start date.

```
date_range = pd.DataFrame()
date_range['End_Date'] = (df['Start_Date'].dt.to_period('M') + month).dt.to_timestamp()
date_range['Start_Date'] = date_range.groupby(groups.ngroup()).shift()
```

> ```
>   Start_Date   End_Date
> 0        NaT 2022-02-01
> 1        NaT 2022-04-01 # <- first
> 2 2022-04-01 2022-05-01 # <- last
> 3        NaT 2022-04-01 # <- first
> 4 2022-04-01 2022-05-01 # <- last
> 5        NaT 2022-07-01
> ```

---

For the first and last rows of each group, you want to fill in the original start/end dates.

```
date_range.loc[month == 1, 'Start_Date'] = df
date_range.loc[month == rows, 'End_Date'] = df
```

> ```
>   Start_Date   End_Date
> 0 2022-01-01 2022-01-05
> 1 2022-03-31 2022-04-01
> 2 2022-04-01 2022-04-03
> 3 2022-03-31 2022-04-01
> 4 2022-04-01 2022-04-03
> 5 2022-06-01 2022-06-05
> ```

---

We add the new dates to the original df and recalculate the nights:

```
df.update(date_range)

df['Nights'] = (df['End_Date'] - df['Start_Date']).dt.days
```

> ```
>   Booking_ID    Name Start_Date   End_Date  Nights
> 0      34532      Me 2022-01-01 2022-01-05       4
> 1      43242  Myself 2022-03-31 2022-04-01       1
> 2      43242  Myself 2022-04-01 2022-04-03       2
> 3      43242     You 2022-03-31 2022-04-01       1
> 4      43242     You 2022-04-01 2022-04-03       2
> 5      32414       I 2022-06-01 2022-06-05       4
> ```

---

Full code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Booking_ID': ['34532', '43242', '43242', '32414'],
     'Name': ['Me', 'Myself', 'You', 'I'],
     'Start_Date': ['Jan 1, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Mar 31, 2022', 'Jun 1, 2022'],
     'End_Date': ['Jan 5, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Apr 3, 2022', 'Jun 5, 2022'],
     'Nights': [4, 3, 3, 4]}
)

df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date']   = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

num_months = 1 + (df['End_Date'].dt.month - df['Start_Date'].dt.month)

df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(num_months)).reset_index(drop=True)

groups = df.groupby(df.columns.to_list())
month  = groups.cumcount() + 1
rows   = groups.transform('size')

date_range = pd.DataFrame()
date_range['End_Date'] = (df['Start_Date'].dt.to_period('M') + month).dt.to_timestamp()
date_range['Start_Date'] = date_range.groupby(groups.ngroup()).shift()

date_range.loc[month == 1, 'Start_Date'] = df
date_range.loc[month == rows, 'End_Date'] = df

df.update(date_range)

df['Nights'] = (df['End_Date'] - df['Start_Date']).dt.days
```